# Extract data from login authentication website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to login first and then extract data from pages which are visible after login. my spider is-

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from loginform import fill_login_form

class ElementSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'login': 'myid', 'password': 'my password'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):

        if "Incorrect username or password" in response.body:
            print "hey"
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        else:
            return Request(url="https://github.com/settings/emails",
                   callback=self.parse_data)


    def parse_data(self, response):
        email = response.xpath('//div[@class="boxed-group-inner"]/li[@class="clearfix css-truncate settings-email"]/span[@class="css-truncate-target"]/text()').extract()
        print email
```

I am getting nothing in the output.
Is there error in implementation ???

Comment: Did you run your class?

Comment: I run spider and the result is simply blannk like []

Comment: please show the command you used to run it

Comment: scrapy crawl example -L WARNING

Comment: And how does that run your `ElementSpider` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created an instance of your class `ElementSpider`.
You first need to create an instance of the class.
**NOTICE**
 Every class should have a constructor, Therefor it is recommended you should implement the `__init__` method in your class.

This is how the code is should to look.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from loginform import fill_login_form

class ElementSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/login']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(ElementSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'login': 'myid', 'password': 'my password'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):

        if "Incorrect username or password" in response.body:
            print "hey"
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        else:
            return Request(url="https://github.com/settings/emails",
                   callback=self.parse_data)


    def parse_data(self, response):
        email = response.xpath('//*[@id="settings-emails"]/li/span[@class="css-truncate-target"]').extract()
        print email


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = ElementSpider()
```

Comment: still the same output

Comment: I don't think this is how a scrapy spider is meant to be ran

Comment: I think that your Xpath is incorrect. Try this `//*[@id="settings-emails"]/li/span[@class="css-truncate-target"]`

Comment: For this you just need to learn `Scrapy` documentation. In this question you asked to help fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error arise in implementation as there is **no "boxed-group-inner"** class in the github.com/settings/emails page.

For correction, change the response.xpath to:

```
response.xpath('//ul[@id="settings-emails"]/li[@class="Box-row clearfix css-truncate settings-email"]/span[@class="css-truncate-target"]/text()').extract()
```

### OR

In this context you can directly use the end node of the html tree as:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="css-truncate-target"]/text()').extract()
```